# HTML/JS/PHP radios, javascript, modals appear and disappear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have page and there is foreach'es.

There is about 4 foreaches with same divs, but different information in divs. Everything is made in modals (bootstrap). And if I select somekinda radio button, div appears. But if I close modal and open up another one, next one is bugged.

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="group1" onchange="show(this.value)"> Show group1<br/>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="group2" onchange="show2()"> Show group2<br/>
    </label>
</div>

<?php
foreach ($array as $row) {
?>
    <div class="group1">
        1 ...
    </div>
    <div class="group2">
        2 ...
    </div>

<?php
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(str){
        $('.group1').show();
        $('.group2').hide();
    }
    function show2(sign){
        $('.group2').show();
        $('.group1').hide();
    }
</script>
```

So should I add lots of JS's or there is another way to make this work well?

Answer (score 0):

Please check you are giving "sign" as a parameter in show2(), which you had called without parameter in your html section.